# Why do we close scanner like this?

Tags: java

I was creating a primality testing program and here's the following snippet.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestPrime {

public static boolean CheckPrimality(int num){

    int factor = 1;
    int limit = (int) Math.sqrt(num);
    for(int i = 2; i<= limit; i++){
        if(num % i == 0){
            factor = i;
        }
    }

    if(factor == 1){
        return true;
    }
    else {return false;}
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        int number = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println(CheckPrimality(number));

        if(reader != null){
            reader.close();
        }

    }

}
```

I'm just confused as to why we close the scanner when 'reader != null'. When the reader is not null, that means there is still stuff in the scanner, right? Why wouldn't we close the scanner when reader IS null instead?

Comment: You're ***really*** not supposed to close the STDIN stream, anyway...

Comment: Checking whether `reader != null` verifies that the `reader` variable points to an instance of `Scanner`. It does not verify whether or not "there is still stuff in the scanner".

Comment: There is no way `reader` can be null at that point. It is a completely redundant null check.

Comment: @Makoto how would I do this without closing the STDIN stream?

Comment: You can use it as you have been - just don't close it. The purpose of `close()` is to release the underlying resource. In the case of `stdin` that's actually a very bad thing.

EDIT: I will add that an additional purpose of `close()` is to flag the object as being closed, which will cause an `IllegalStateException` to be thrown if you attempt to use it again. So it's a way of protecting yourself against trying to re-use something which should not be re-used. In the case above though, the `Scanner` is a local variable so you already know that nothing else will attempt to access it after `main`.

Answer (score 0):

To be blunt:  you shouldn't be closing STDIN.  You don't know what other parts of the application (even those that you didn't implement) may still be using that stream.

> I'm just confused as to why we close the scanner when 'reader != null'. When the reader is not null, that means there is still stuff in the scanner, right?

No.  This is a `Scanner` that has nothing in its buffer, yet is non-null:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
```

If you want to see if anything still left in the scanner, then you can use `hasNext()` or `hasNextLine()`, depending on what you need to verify.

> Why wouldn't we close the scanner when reader IS null instead?

What would we be closing then?  The `.close()` method lives on an instance of `Scanner`, and if that's `null`, then we'd be doing this:

```
Scanner badScanner = null;
badScanner.close(); // NullPointerException
```

If you're concerned about resource management, a `Scanner` in Java 7 implements [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), so you can use a `try`-with-resources to handle the closure of the stream (but please, not STDIN).

```
try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("myFile.txt")) {
    // work done with file
}
```

In Java 6 and below, you can use a `try...finally` block to accomplish the same thing.

```
Scanner scan = null;
try {
    scan = new Scanner(new File("myFile.txt"));
    // work done with file
} finally {
    scan.close();
}
```